# Solving $(y'')(y'-y)(y''+4y)^2=11e^x-\sin(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this equation. I have solved the homogeneous part as:

$y(x)=ae^x$ or
$y(x)=ax+b$ or
$y(x)=a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)$ correct me if I am wrong,
but stuck with the particular part. Can you direct me?

$(y'')(y'-y)(y''+4y)^2=11e^x-\sin(2x)$

Comment: No I am not sure :)

Comment: @ Olcat Ertas:  *where* did you get *that* equation?

Comment: It is from my homework

Comment: Your homogeneous solutions are good.For the rest, I'm as stumped as you; W|A outputs "second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation" and goes no further as "Standard computation time exceeded..".

Comment: @OlcayErtaş: Did you progress?

Comment: @Amzoti no progress. Still trying...

Comment: Nolinear DEs have no concepts that general solution $=$ complementary solution $+$ particular solution.

Comment: If the question is $y''(y'-y)(y''+4y)^2=11e^x$ then we can rewrite it as $\dfrac{y''}{y}\left(\dfrac{y'}{y}-1\right)\left(\dfrac{y''}{y}+4\right)^2=\dfrac{11e^x}{y^4}$ which belongs to an ODE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0511.pdf